# Is there anyway to inbuilt C# function to generate a valid CSS class name?

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Is there an inbuilt ASP.Net or MVC3 function that generates a valid CSS class given a string. Tagbuilder seems to have one AddCssClass. However just wondering if there is anything else that takes a string and converts it to valid CSS Class name by converting invalid characters to valid ones?

As an example say I have a string "Test. Bad Class Name"

I was wondering if there was a helper function to convert this to "Test__Bad Class_Name" or some such thing.

MVC doesn't seem to generate bad IDs etc so I just wondered if it had something that did this so I was being consistent. I just thought it would be a common requirement.

Comment: What makes you think that `TagBuilder.AddCssClass` generates a valid CSS name? You could throw just any crap at it and it will accept it :-) It's your responsibility not to throw crap at it. AFAIK there's no built-in method for this.

Comment: You want a helper function to generate a CSS class (e.g. `.test { color: Red }`), or you just want a way to assign a class name (e.g. test) to a DOM element in your code (code-behind or view)?  I'm not sure I totally understand what you want.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov maybe I was thinking of the ID generation. I think it swaps out dots so I thought class names were converted to be valid. Guess not! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string className = Regex.Replace(myInput, @"[^a-zA-Z_\-]+", "_");
```

I know this pattern is overly zealous and replaces characters it shouldn't, like numbers, but it will give you a one-way function for generating valid css class names.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was overly optimistic thinking it was inbuilt.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you cannot guarantee, with this method, that two different inputs always generate different outcome. Like `"some class"` and `"some,class"` both give `"some_class"`

Comment: Yeah I appreciate that. Be more than good enough for my requirement. Just didn't want to go adding code if I was missing an obvious in built function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's @atornblad solution as an extension method

```
    public static string ToValidClassName(this string srcString)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(srcString, @"[^a-zA-Z_\-]+", "_");
    }
```

Makes it 'feel' built in :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is also [XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodelocalname.aspx), which is not pretty, but it is reversible. Xml name and css class have similar naming constrains.